# Почему неправильно сохраняется пользователь в приложении андроид?

Tags: android

Я у себя в приложении пробую сохранить пользователя во время регистрации, что-бы потом при дальнейшем использовании приложения не нужно было вводить пароль и логин.

Для того что-бы как-то идентифицировать пользователя на устройстве я сохраняю рефреш токен который был присвоен юзеру во время регистрации. Я его сохраняю в sharedpreferences и дальше при запуске приложения проверяю присутствует ли такая настройка, вот мой код:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_login);


        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(REFRESH_TOKEN, MODE_PRIVATE);
        // проверяем, первый ли раз открывается программа
        boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);


        if (!hasVisited) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            try {
                submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
                submitBtn.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
                submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        sendPost();
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                        SendLogcatMail(thread, ex);
                    }
                });


            }
        }

    }
```

но у меня почему-то регулируется проверка одним знаком восклицания в условии ,то есть либо я сразу перехожу дальше по приложению, либо идет логин в приложении. Вероятнее всего я что-то не правильно прописал.

### UPDATE

сохранения токена для проверки:

```
refresh_pref = getSharedPreferences("refresh_token", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = refresh_pref.edit();
editor1.putString(REFRESH_TOKEN, token2);
editor1.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
editor1.apply();
```

мой метод OnCreate() почти не изменился за исключением только убранного !. Сохранение токена происходит при первом логине в приложение.

Если кто-то заметил у меня ошибку или неправильную реализацию моей задумки, то буду очень благодарен вашим советам и любой другой помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А где же у Вас `editor.put("hasVisited", true)`?

Comment: а эта строка может быть такой - editor.putBoolean("hasVisited", true)? я просто походу провтыкал здесь запись переменной сделать) я вот попробовал вставить эту строку, но почему-то все равно открывается сразу второе активити

Comment: я вот тут набрел на такой вариант как splashactivity, может данное решение будет лучше чем то что я делаю проверку в главном классе?

Comment: Splash не исправит ошибки в коде и его задача развлекать юзера при длительной (больше "пары секунд") подготовке к работе. Насчёт `putBoolean` - да, должно быть так, но Вы такой товарищ, что я не могу угадать куда Вы её вписали, поэтому обновляйте вопрос и **!** долой из условия.

Comment: обновил вопрос, если чего-то не выложил, то говорите обновлю еще раз

Comment: вроде-бы все работает как нужно, но теперь логика приложения страдает по не понятной мне причине

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас получается следующее.
Как я понимаю  проблема в этом кусочке кода:

```
 if (!hasVisited) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Если hasVisited == false, тогда идет переход на 2-ой экран.
Но ведь переход на второй экран должен быть только в том случае, когда hasVisited = true.

Comment: да @АнтонМартынов Вы совершенно правы, если убрать восклицательный знак, то у меня не будет на старте приложения сразу переход на второй экран, а будет форма логина, возможно на эмуляторе не совсем правильно сохраняются данные, но мой способ не решает мою задачу.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko смотрите, значит у вас hasVisited = false, следовательно могу сделать вывод, что в SharedPreference нет такого ключа.
Что скажете?

Comment: чисто гипотетически может быть так, что из-за того что я ставлю приложение на эмулятор, при переустановке приложение сносится, вообще во время первого логина создается ключ с токеном

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, нет, приложение не сносится. Все нормально. Только что проверил на своем проекте.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko покажите код, где вы сохраняется токен в sp